# How to fill sub-items listView with a string-array?

Tags: java, android

In my project i have two string arrays, and i want to fill a list view like the example below

first string array items {a,b,c,d,e,f}
second string array items {1,2,3,4,5,6}

here is my code

```
ListView lv;
String A[] = {"A","B","B","D","E","F"};
String B[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_search_view);


    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewtenses);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,A));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
}
```

Where and how i have to put the B array?
i want to fill the listView with the two arrays.
the A array to Items and the B array to subitems

Comment: I guess you need to do it in your `adapter` inside of method `getView()` another way you will not access subitems.

Comment: You can use ArrayList with model class , and then you can store two arrays in single list and you can pass that array list to adapter.

Comment: Could you please send me a piece of code because im a beginner?